# Does Google Analytics have a fixed IP?

Tags: google-analytics

This is probably a dumb question but does www.google-analytics.com have a fixed IP? I ask because due to the vagaries of the project I'm on we need to make sure that traffic aimed at www.google-analytics.com (i.e. traffic from our website) does not get blocked at a certain point in the network. We can ensure it is not blocked with a rule, but the rule demands both a URL and IP address.

So do you know, is the IP address for Google Analytics fixed?

Cheers!

Dave

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but https://www.google.com/analytics is a website for dns servers to be able to find that website the IP address associated with the website would have to have a static IP address.   This really should be on  http://superuser.com/ I think

Comment: The other question you should ask yourself is "do I want to base a business critical decision on something that is not part of the documentation, and thus subject to unannounced changes". When in doubt you can build a proxy via the measurement protocol (or a service like https://segment.com/) to a known server outside the firewall and send the data from there.